# How do I obtain the newly released Generation II Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ever since the release of Pokémon Go, I have only been able to find and hatch Pokémon from Generation I.

How do I obtain the newly released Generation II Pokémon, and which Pokémon am I able to collect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the newest update by Niantic, [Johto Holiday](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/johto-holiday/), they released the first addition of Pokémon from the Johto Region:

> Professor Willow has discovered Togepi and Pichu hatching from Eggs! Starting later today, Trainers will have the opportunity to hatch these and several other Pokémon that were originally discovered in the Johto Region in Pokémon Gold and Pokémon Silver video games. These are the first of more Pokémon coming to Pokémon GO over the next few months.

Based on [this chart](http://www.polygon.com/2016/12/13/13939734/how-to-get-new-pokemon-in-pokemon-go-eggs), the following "baby" Pokémon have been released for different eggs

> 1. Cleffa - 2k egg
> 2. Igglybuff - 2k egg
> 3. Pichu - 5k egg
> 4. Togepi - 5k egg
> 5. Smoochum - 10k egg
> 6. Elekid - 10k egg
> 7. Magby - 10k egg

Comment: I know it's a quote, but perhaps edit out the Niantic self-promotion?

Comment: @Ellesedil Done

Comment: *NOW* how am I going to finish Kanto?

Comment: @Vemonus "To post a question use the top right button on your page" (Lol jk jk). This is the next "spam" question that will pop up. So many of those will pop I'm pretty sure.